# Compilation error: Cannot us a method returning CompetionStage as a Handler for requests

Tags: java, scala, playframework, java-8, playframework-2.5

I'm having trouble with an action that has to do an asynchonous task. The action returns a CompletionStage so that the server won't be blocked by the async task (doSearch() method) and when the task is complete I can call complete() to respond to the client. Here's the action inside controllers/Application.java:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static CompletionStage<Result> search(String secret) {
    CompletableFuture<Result> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    if (!hasPermission(secret)) {
        result.complete(unauthorized("Secret is incorrect."));
        return result;
    }
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null) {
        result.complete(badRequest("Expecting json data."));
        return result;
    }

    SearchRequestBody search = Json.fromJson(json, SearchRequestBody.class);
    doSearch(search.body).thenApply(searchResults -> {
        result.complete(ok(Json.toJson(searchResults)));
        return null;
    });
    return result;
}
```

routes file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

#PUT     /predict/:id                controllers.Application.predict()

GET    /search                     controllers.Application.search
```

The error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to C:\Users\senok\IdeaProjects\Culinars\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\senok\IdeaProjects\Culinars\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\Users\senok\IdeaProjects\Culinars\conf\routes:13: Cannot use a method returning java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[play.mvc.Result] as a Handler for requests
[error] GET    /search                     controllers.Application.search
[error] C:\Users\senok\IdeaProjects\Culinars\conf\routes:13: not enough arguments for method createInvoker: (implicit hif: play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory[java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[play.mvc.Result]])play.core.routing.HandlerInvoker[java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[play.mvc.Result]].
[error] Unspecified value parameter hif.
[error] GET    /search                     controllers.Application.search
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] application - 

! @715l00c2i - Internal server error, for (GET) [/search] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Cannot use a method returning java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[play.mvc.Result] as a Handler for requests]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
```

EDIT: Here's doSearch:

```
private static CompletableFuture<List<SearchResult>> doSearch(Map<String, String>[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<List<SearchResult>> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    List<SearchResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    final int[] paramsLeft = new int[]{args.length};
    for (Map<String, String> param : args) {
        if (!param.containsKey("type")
                || !param.containsKey("uid")
                || !param.containsKey("importance")) {
            paramsLeft[0]--;
            if (paramsLeft[0] == 0)
                result.complete(results);
        } else {
            String nodeName = "";
            switch (param.get("type")) {
                case "ingredient":
                    nodeName = "ingredients";
                    break;
                case "tag":
                    nodeName = "tags";
                    break;
                case "keyword":
                    nodeName = "keywords";
                    break;
                default:
                    paramsLeft[0]--;
                    if (paramsLeft[0] == 0)
                        result.complete(results);
            }
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(nodeName).child(param.get("uid"));
            ref.child("recipes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        paramsLeft[0]--;
                        if (paramsLeft[0] == 0)
                            result.complete(results);
                        return;
                    }
                    for (DataSnapshot recipe : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult();
                        searchResult.uid = recipe.getKey();
                        searchResult.matching = Double.parseDouble(param.get("importance"));
                        int index = results.indexOf(searchResult);
                        if (index > -1)
                            results.get(index).combine(searchResult);
                        else
                            results.add(searchResult);
                    }
                    paramsLeft[0]--;
                    if (paramsLeft[0] == 0) {
                        result.complete(results);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    paramsLeft[0]--;
                    if (paramsLeft[0] == 0)
                        result.complete(results);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `doSearch` method code?

Comment: @Salem The change you suggested still resulted in a compile error. I posted doSearch, but I highly doubt it has to do with that. It looks more like a bug, since the compiler rejects the function outright because it returns CompletionStage<Result>. I solved the issue for now though, explained in my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since all actions are wrapped inside their own CompletionStage by default, we can make it return a Result instead, still keeping it asynchonous. Here's the new return statement:

```
return result.get(); //Locks the thread until result.complete() is called.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last part of your method to this:

```
SearchRequestBody search = Json.fromJson(json, SearchRequestBody.class);
return doSearch(search.body).thenApply(searchResults -> {
    return ok(Json.toJson(searchResults));
});
```

If you still get compilation errors please post the code of `doSearch`